# Is partial double glazing worthwhile?

Tags: insulation

My house has single glazed windows. I understand that bubblewrap can act like double glazing, however doing this will ruin my views.

Is there much advantage in only covering part of the Windows (say 50% -  the parts behind the curtains and close to the floor)?   Im interested both from a power saving and "crying Windows" POV.

Are there any other "low cost", fairly easy ways to improve my window insulation which do not require modifying window frames that I can do myself with only basic skills? Getting this professionally done would not seem to make sense from a cost POV.

Answer (score 1):

You can DIY install low-e (low-emittance) storm windows that retain the views and  dramatically reduce window heat loss. There are operable storm windows that don't need to be removed seasonally.

https://www.energy.gov/energysaver/services/do-it-yourself-energy-savings-projects/savings-project-install-exterior-storm